# SQL Change Text To Unique ID Number

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a MySql database that contains two tables. One table (the 'Country' table) has a list of countries (the columns are unique_id and country_name). The other table (the 'State') table has a list of global regions (equivalent to the U.S' States). Columns in the States table are state_id, state_name, country_name).

I would like to convert all the country names in the 'State' table to the corresponding unique-id in the 'Country' table. Is there a way to do this?

Any help appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: How many countries are in the United States?

Comment: Pls post the approach you have taken , so that we can let you know , where you need help.

Comment: lol... i'm not being clear. The States table actually contains various regions from a number of countries... i just named the table 'State' for convenience.

Comment: Please provide tables structure, sample data and desired output to make your question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select data to see unique id instead of country name you can use inner join

```
select StateId, StateName, UniqueId from states
INNER JOIN countries
ON states.CountryName = countries.CountryName;
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a new column, to hold the foreign key:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE State
     ADD COLUMN country_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES Country (unique_id);  -- optional
   ```

   The line marked `optional` above adds a [foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), which will only work if: (i) both tables use the InnoDB engine; (ii) `State.country_id` and `Country.unique_id` are the same data type; and (iii) `Country.unique_id` is indexed (it should probably be that table's *primary key*).
2. Populate the new column using a multiple-table `UPDATE`:

   ```
   UPDATE State JOIN Country USING (country_name)
   SET    State.country_id = Country.unique_id;
   ```
3. Drop the original column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE State
     DROP COLUMN country_name,
     MODIFY country_id BIGINT NOT NULL;   -- optional
   ```

   The line marked `optional` above forces every `State` to have a `country_id`.